# Convert str type dicts with nan values to dict type objects

Tags: pandas, csv, dictionary, abstract-syntax-tree

Similar questions to this have been asked many times, but surprisingly few of the answers seem to address what I believe my problem to be.

I have csv files with one or more columns that contain a dictionary in each cell. After `read_csv` step, I have tried `ast.literal_eval` on these columns in order to convert the str format dicts into dict type objects. However, I keep getting the `malformed node or string` error.

Here is a typical example of the dicts in question: `{1: 3681.45, 0: 3693.3333333333335}`. And another, with a `nan` value: `{1: 4959.95652173913, 0: nan}`. Edit: It was *only* this `nan` value causing the error, in fact (see Rakesh's solution below).

Looking through previous answers, one reason for this error may be because most of the values of the dicts in these columns are floating point numbers, and apparently `literal_eval` can't handle floats or nans, even if they're contained within dictionaries (although, this is me inferring from a question about tuples).

I had to read a lot of questions and answers even to get this much information, so thought it could be useful to start a new topic with the keywords `str`, `dict`, but also `nan` in the title.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: @Rakesh Sure, I've added a typical example, and also one with a nan value, which may create added trouble of its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval` on json that has `nan`

**Ex:**

```
import ast
from numpy import nan

print(ast.literal_eval("{1: 3681.45, 0: 3693.3333333333335}"))
print(eval("{1: 4959.95652173913, 0: nan}"))
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["{1: 4959.95652173913, 0: nan}", "{1: 4959.95652173913, 0: nan}"]})
df['B'] = df["A"].apply(lambda x: eval(x))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                               A                              B
0  {1: 4959.95652173913, 0: nan}  {1: 4959.95652173913, 0: nan}
1  {1: 4959.95652173913, 0: nan}  {1: 4959.95652173913, 0: nan}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rakesh. I had just figured out that it was only the 'nan' values causing the error, so I'm going to update my question. A small supplementary question; in other topics around this subject, people talk a lot about using eval only if you have trusted data to input. Is this still a consideration to bear in mind?

Comment: Also, you don't call attention to it, but I find the simple direct import of nan very elegant as a way to get around the fact that it is not np.nan in the dictionary! Thank you again.

Comment: One hiccup remains: this works for converting a single instance, but not when converting a column: 
df['Examples'] = df['Examples'].apply(eval)
This still returns, "NameError: name 'nan' is not defined"

Comment: Use `lambda` in apply.

Comment: Okay, thanks a million, that works! I don't exactly understand why that works, but I suppose I can study that myself a bit.

Comment: The solution using eval(STR_DICT_CONTAINING_NAN) is not working for me. Please see screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/U0gGeLv